# GitHub on Android Studio

Tags: android, github, android-studio

I have a main GitHub account shared by multiple people, and we each have our own account.  I created a repository through Android Studio using the main account, and now I was to push code from my personal account.  So I go to the GitHub settings under `File > Settings` and change the login credentials to reflect my personal account.  However, when I push the code it still says the commit was made by the main account, and that it is the only contributor.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe when you set up git with your new account it didn't change gitconfig

Try:

```
git config --global user.name "Amir"
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

(note --global is optional , it will make it your name/email everywhere on the system)

Comment: Isn't the git user different than the github account though?

Comment: So it shows up from the previous github account?
Did you check again in Settings -> Version Control - > Github to check whether it saved the new one?

Comment: Yeah it saved the new one. I even tried leaving the fields blank.  Then it prompted me for a github username and password so I supplied the personal one and it still registered as the shared one

Comment: Actually, it says my personal account pushed it, but it's still authored by the shared one

Comment: So on github it says it's made by the shared account?
It might be reusing the old token , you might have to clone it again.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the solution by @LeonardoC solves the problem, but if you want to know why this was happening you can read this: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/

Particularly, the part that says:

> **GitHub uses the email address in the commit header to link the commit to a GitHub user**. If your commits are being linked to another user, or not linked to a user at all, you may need to **change your local Git configuration settings**, add an email address to your account email settings, or do both.
>
> Note: If your commits are linked to another user, that does not mean the user can access your repository. A user can only access a repository you own if you add them as a collaborator or add them to a team that has access to the repository

So, to change your local Git configuration settings you type the two instructions aforementioned by @LeonardoC:

```
git config --global user.name "yourUsername"
git config --global user.email "theEmailLinkedToYourUsername"
```

And just in case you want to check what are the values before changing them, you can get them by just typing in the shell:

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```